# Best Way to Render HTML in WinForms application?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a WinForms application, running on .net 3.5. This Application generates HTML on the fly, which includes the complete document, and also an inline-CSS-Stylesheet (inside the head element).

I am using the WebBrowser control and setting browser.DocumentText to my generated HTML, but that does not seem to properly apply styles on the body element (I've set background-color to #000000 in the CSS, but the background is still white).

I wonder if a) there are some alternatives to render relatively simple HTML in C# (i.e. a completely managed HTML renderer) or b) what would be the best way to render HTML using the WebBrowser control, including correct handling of inline-css and without using a temporary file on the hard drive.

**Edit:** The CSS-not-applying issue was a separate problem. I've put my actual CSS in a CDATA block, which seems to cause it not to apply correctly. That is now fixed, but the question itself still stands.

Comment: It was stupid to close this question just because it has the word "best" in the title! It's a good question and it helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stayed with the built-in WebBrowser. The HtmlRenderer from the other answer is great, but renders an image.

Comment: The HtmlRenderer has been updated since and now has full support for text selection, copy-paste, etc. FYI.

Comment: I tried adding the WinForms nuget package but when i add the Html panel to a form visual studio crashes ..

Answer (score 16):

For managed HTML renderer see [HtmlRenderer](https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer) on GitHub.

Comment: Now that looks sexy, going to give it a try.

Comment: There is a newer version at [CodePlex](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) and it seems that development moved to there. A great component really.

Comment: This is superior to the internal WebBrowser, which has additional COM overhead and doesn't play well with the thread apartment model [Read: I could not get WebBrowser to work when it is launched from a BackgroundWorker thread]. And the component is only 200K!

Answer (score 0):

Your could look into using a view engine.
Most view engines can work in a stand-alone api manner

for example NHaml and nvelocity both can be used stand alone

http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/

http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html

And i assume Spark can be as well

http://dev.dejardin.org/

Comment: I don't think that those will do be any good - to my understanding, they create HTML from a template. I am looking for something that renders HTML on screen, aka. a Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed what you were asking for: a "*completely managed HTML renderer*", which will "*render relatively simple HTML in C#*". It supports a subset of CSS, which you can "*specify in a inline CSS stylesheet (inside the head element)*".

For details, see [the ModelText HTML control](http://www.modeltext.com/html/).