# Web browser in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I need to view a web page inside my application (developed using C# with Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0), so I need to create a simple like browser.  This browser can pass a value to system. I have tried [CefSharp](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp.git) and [webkit](http://webkit.org) with no luck - I cannot load the assembly into Visual Studio.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use WebBrowser component?

Comment: Why not a WebBrowser Control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Way to Render HTML in WinForms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218325/best-way-to-render-html-in-winforms-application)

Answer (score 6):

If this is WinForms, you should consider using the [WebBrowser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) which embeds Internet Explorer as a user control.

WPF also has a similar webbrowser control defined like this:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="wbMain" Margin="30">
</WebBrowser>
```

Many scenarios are already covered in the .Net framework, and it's easier to use what comes with the framework before trying other things. That said, there are scenarios where you might want to use something other than the IE webbrowser control, but try the easy way first.

Comment: +1. OP tries very unorthodox methods and totaly ignores what is arleady there.

Comment: is it possible to pass variable back to the system from webbrowser class?

Comment: Yes, you can access every DOM element on the web page and use it in your code.

Comment: i just try your solution, it's a good solution, but because of the webbrowser class use a IE as a browser, and my web application has been tested with Mozilla/chrome, i found a problem when viewed the web application.

Comment: fattah, Creating a webapp which doesn't work with all the defacto browsers in 2011 is bad practice imo. And it's not that hard to get html to work with IE7+, FireFox, Chrome and Safari. It's probably easier to fix the html, than to use another browser engine.

Comment: Worth nothing, the WebBrowser control uses the locally installed version of IE. If your machine runs IE6, your application will run IE6. **shudders**

Comment: Sergio, true, but who has IE6 today, except old citrix servers with unpatched XP's. But I see your point, and unfortunately it's still valid some places.

Comment: Owh, thanks mikael and sergio. the web application is an existing web application, and it's hard for me to change the code. i think one of the solution is to prevent web browser from run when it's detect an IE6 is installed and the user need to upgrade to the latest IE.