# how to insert a html code in c# windows application project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

I am working on c#,visual studio 2013.
I want to add some html code in my windows application project,so can anybody suggest me how to link or add html code?
Please help me.just got tired of searching.[enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator)

Comment: In what way you want to add HTML Code? You want to show rendered HTML output on the window or you want to show the code ?? please make it little more clear to understand the quesiton

Comment: i want to add add this code (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator)
and don't know how to add please help me,i can explain my question more again n again but need solution.

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question really is here. If you're asking how to render a HTML page in a C# based application, I am sure you can use WPF to render it somehow, I can't find the component I believed would do this though. You could use something like a WebClient to render the page, but I am not sure this would work very well.

Another similar question was asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218325/best-way-to-render-html-in-winforms-application)

Again, sorry but I am not really sure what the question is.